# React in laravel is getting syntaxerror unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, laravel-mix

I realize this question has been asked a lot but I can't find an answer.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

According to a post in laracasts in regards to react in Laravel Jeffrey Way says:
Just do:

```
mix.react('src', 'output');
```

And we'll install all the necessary Babel plugins and setup your .babelrc.

In my project I currently have a component and in my react mix file I have this:

```
mix.react('resources/assets/js/basicapp.js', 'public/js');
```

my basicapp.js file is a simple component setup like so:

```
require('./components/Reactapp');
```

When I run mix it creates an error:
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (43:17)

```
  41 |   }
  42 | 
> 43 |   toggleSelected = (id, key) => {
     |                  ^
  44 |     let temp = [...this.state[key]]
  45 |     temp[id].selected = !temp[id].selected
  46 |     this.setState({
```

I've been racking my brain over this for two days now!  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: After checking there is no .babelrc file according to the instructions by Jeffrey Way this should automatically be done by laravel.

Comment: please provide your `.babelrc`

Comment: There is no .babelrc file, I just checked.  I updated the answer also.  @Nguyễn Thanh Tú  is there a boiler plate one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further review Laravel doesn't just work with es6.  I had to add a .babelrc file and then add some dependencies to the package.json

I added this to package.json devDependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
```

this was already there:

```
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
```

in .babelrc file I added this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "react",
        "stage-0",
        [
            "env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "browsers": [
                        "last 2 versions",
                        "safari >= 7"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: the plugin entry should be :  {
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
} See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties and https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration#switch-to-proposal-for-tc39-proposals-blog-2017-12-27-nearing-the-70-releasehtml-renames-proposal

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this as a comment but I don't have enough points to comment. But does it work if you don't use es6 syntax?

```
toggleSelected(id, key){}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toggleSelected = (id, key) => {
......
}
```

You are using what is called class fields/properties syntax for your event handler. 
This syntax is an experimental feature which can only be used when you provide the following :
@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties 
See [proposal class properties](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties)

You need to install the plugin by using this command :

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```